# Google spreadsheet: removed GS code, but afte send xhttp.open('GET request from Captivate, the Spreadsheet still run original code

Tags: google-apps-script

thanks for helping.

I just set up google spreadsheet and GS code, Captivate JS code following :

http://elearningbrothers.com/how-to-create-a-leaderboard-elearning-google/

http://elearningbrothers.com/how-to-create-a-leaderboard-elearning-google-part-2/

This worked. But after I removed the GS code from the spreadsheet, the Spreadsheet still run original code. (I wanted to modify the code for my use, however, the spreadsheet always runs the original code. Then I removed the whole code and see what is happening.)

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Script Editor in Menu > Publish > Deploy As Web Apps, select new project version and click update because Web Apps has old version of script you delete
so you need to refresh new version of your now script

> **More**

[Web Apps - Deploying Script As Web App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploying_a_script_as_a_web_app)

Comment: could you help on this also:I created a Captivate project that runs JS (following code) when click on a Submit a Textbox. The JS works on Captivate Preview in HTML5 environment. But why this does not work on Scorm Cloud? (after I click submit, this JS seems not started and not goes to the php page: see code) Thanks 
JS COde :     window.location.href = "http://icanpassdrivingschool.com/phpcode/record5.php?w1=" + ls_lastname + "&w2=" + ls_lastname;

Comment: According to the terms you need to make post answered and create new one with TAGS of your problem